# Inserting a "linked rectangle" with itext

Tags: itext

I want to insert a hyperlink into an existing PDF at a position I know in advance: I already have the coordinates of a rectangle on a given page. I want to link this rectangle to another page of the same PDF (which I also know in advance).

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [AddLinkAnnotation](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/AddLinkAnnotation) example.

As you (should) already know (but you didn't show what you've already tried, which is kind of mandatory on StackOverflow), you can use `PdfStamper` to manipulate an existing PDF. Adding a rectangular link on one page to another page, is as simple as adding a *link annotation* to that page:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
Rectangle linkLocation = new Rectangle(523, 770, 559, 806);
PdfDestination destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
        linkLocation, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,
        3, destination);
link.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));
stamper.addAnnotation(link, 1);
stamper.close();
```

The `link` object is created using:

- the `writer` instance tied to the `stamper`,
- the rectangle (the position you say you know in advance,
- a highlighting option (pick one: HIGHLIGHT_NONE, HIGHLIGHT_INVERT, HIGHLIGHT_OUTLINE, HIGHLIGHT_PUSH, HIGHLIGHT_TOGGLE),
- the page you want to link to,
- a destination (different options are possible, see [The ABC of PDF](https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc)).

Once you have an instance of `PdfAnnotation`, you can add it to a specific page using the `addAnnotation()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But could you please tell me how to get rid of the black border around the annotations? (The border doesn't have to do with the highlight option I guess: it is there even with HIGHLIGHT_NONE.)

Comment: I've added a single line to my answer. It removes the border.