# How to insert a iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle at an absolute position?

Tags: .net, itext

Using the code below, the rectangle inserted is at the bottom-left of the page.   How can a `iTextSharp.text.Rectangle` rectangle be inserted at an absolute position?  Thanks.

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 15, 0);  
// (lower-left-x, lower-left-y, upper-right-x (llx + width), upper-right-y (lly + height), rotation angle 
rectangle.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
rectangle.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.YELLOW;
overContent.Rectangle(rectangle);
//stamper.Close();
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateLink(
                        stamper.Writer, rectangle, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,
                        new PdfAction("http://itextpdf.com/"));
stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, 1);
```

Comment: Greyson:  Thanks for your response.  Your code works in general.  However, the Hyperlink rectangle is ALWAYS at the bottom-left of the generated PDF no matter how I change the x & y values in the Rectangle arguments (int x, int y, int width, int height).  Could you provide your advisory how to insert the Rectangle at a desired position?

Comment: We can't reproduce the problem. I see that you are doing something awkward though. You are adding the rectangle to the actual content: `overContent.Rectangle(rectangle);` and you are using the same `rectangle` to create an annotation. You shouldn't do this. Create your annotation and draw its border as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194844 (Actually I think that this question should be marked as a duplicate of that question.)

Comment: I see you asked a followup question on the iText mailing list. Probably not a good idea, because that list hardly has any traffic. It's best to just edit your question here.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment the OP says

> the Hyperlink rectangle is ALWAYS at the bottom-left of the generated PDF no matter how I change the x & y values in the **Rectangle arguments (int x, int y, int width, int height)**.

Here the mistake becomes apparent, the OP assumes the third and fourth parameter of the `Rectangle` constructor to be the width and height. This is not the case, cf. the documented source code of the `Rectangle` constructors:

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructs a Rectangle-object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="llx">lower left x</param>
/// <param name="lly">lower left y</param>
/// <param name="urx">upper right x</param>
/// <param name="ury">upper right y</param>
public Rectangle(float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury)

...

/**
 * Constructs a <CODE>Rectangle</CODE>-object.
 *
 * @param llx   lower left x
 * @param lly   lower left y
 * @param urx   upper right x
 * @param ury   upper right y
 * @param rotation the rotation (0, 90, 180, or 270)
 * @since iText 5.0.6
 */
public Rectangle(float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury, int rotation)
```

and cf. also the comment in the OP's own code:

```
// (lower-left-x, lower-left-y, upper-right-x (llx + width), upper-right-y (lly + height), rotation angle
```

The third and fourth parameter are the coordinates of a second point. The rectangle location and size is determined by the diagonal from `(llx, lly)` to `(urx, ury)`.

Furthermore, in spite of the variable names and descriptions iTextSharp does not enforce the first point to be in the lower left and the second in the upper right; if the second is in the lower right or lower left, so be it...

Thus, as the OP only changed the first two parameters, the second point remained at `(100, 15)` which usually is very near the page bottom and quite near to the page left border.

He should try something like instead:

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(510, 510, 600, 515, 0);
```